# IdHttp HTTPS Handshake Failure

Tags: ssl, indy10, delphi-xe8

Delphi: XE 8

Indy ver: 10.6.2

Open SSL Library Produce Ver: 1.0.2q (ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll)

I'm getting the following error from my Delphi app when trying to make the following **Get** call:

> Error connecting with SSL. error:14094410:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure.

```
procedure TfrmPushToCertify.Push;
var
  stsJSON  : TStringStream;
  strmResp : TMemoryStream;
  stlResp  : TStringList;

  RecID :  String;
  GetURL:  String;
  PostURL: String;
  PutURL:  String;

begin

  strmResp := TMemoryStream.Create;
  BuildRESTHeaders;
  IdHTTP_Certify.Get('https://api.certify.com/v1/exprptglds/1?code=15213|N800KS', strmResp);

end;
```

I can make the same call successfully using Postman (so I know the API call is correct & the server is responding).

[image: WireShark Screen Print]

The problem seems to be "ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT" but I don't know what that means or how to fix it.

I upgraded to the new DLLs, ver 1.0.2q but no change in result. Still fails w/ same message.

Comment: You are using an old version of OpenSSL. You should be using 1.0.2 instead of 1.0.0. In fact, I'm surprised Wireshark says TLSv1.2 since 1.2 wasn't added to OpenSSL until 1.0.1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: the lines with TLSv1.2 are to and from different addresses, hence for different (and nonfailed) connections. The record version _for ClientHello_ is not reliable anyway; OpenSSL sends record version 1.0 even when the handshake content allows 1.1 or 1.2 (for better interop) and for 1.3 it uses record version 1.0 and message fixed version 1.2 with 1.3 indicated only in the new extension 43 (as is _required_ by RFC8446 for better interop). In any case, although 1.2 is preferable, that server does accept 1.0 -- at least for now.

Comment: OP: try looking at the ClientHello to see if it includes extension 'server_name' (officially Server Name Indication, SNI). That server is really cloudfront, a CDN that serves many domains on the same IP address(es) so it _requires_ SNI to know what cert to use. I don't know how Delphi/Indy versions and/or features affect using SNI, though.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Indy has [supported SNI on outbound client connections for a few years now](https://www.indyproject.org/2016/01/10/client-side-sni-support-added-to-tidssliohandlersocketopenssl/) (but not on inbound server connections yet).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I upgraded OpenSSL to 1.0.2q but no changes.  It still fails with the same error.  Is there a way to force TIdHTTP to use TLSv1.2 (instead of TLSv1) for the Client Hello?

Comment: @user1424415 make sure the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions.SSLVersions` property contains only `sslvTLSv1_2`. By default, it contains `sslvTLSv1` (TLS 1.0) instead.

Comment: I don't see SSLVersions as a property of HTTPOptions of my IdHTTP_Certify object.  I do however find it on the TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions and it has only sslvTLSv1_2. (TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL is assigned as the IOHandler for my IdHTTP_Certify object.)  And I still get the same error.  Any other suggestions?